# Difference between 2 ways of using AJAX

Tags: ajax, jquery

I want to understand the difference between using AJAX like this,

```
function showHint(str)
{
var xmlhttp;
if (str.length==0)
  { 
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","db_update?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

and using it like this..

```
$.ajax({
     url: "db_update.php",
     type: "POST",
     data: { id: id, state: state },
     cache: false,
     success: function (response) {
         $('#text').html(response);
     }
 });
```

how different is one from the other? which is efficient?

Comment: One uses a third party library (jQuery) to do the work (second one). The other is hand coded. I would suspect that the first is more efficient (that's just a guess) whereas the second is certainly more robust.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comment section, the first one is using standard Javascript to make the Ajax request, whereas the second one is using JQuery. This does essentially the same thing, however the second version is less tedious and clearer.
Regarding performance, I guess JQuery is supposed to be optimized so it shouldn't be too different. In the end it's just a wrapper. You could probably do better by writing your own specific code, but you'd have to look out for cross browsers compatility and other issues, where JQuery takes care of that for you.